# Want to add a legend to 3D plot made by combining three plots with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have this code:

```
PIC1 = Plot3D[Cos[x] Cos[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
PIC2 = 
  Plot3D[-(x - Pi/2) (y + Pi/2), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"];
PIC3 = 
  Plot3D[(x - Pi/2) (y + Pi/2), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"];
Show[PIC1, PIC2, PIC3]
```

[image]

and I want to a legend of the form

```
PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend["Expressions"]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not just put them all in a single plot? `Plot3D[{Cos[x] Cos[y], -(x - Pi/2) (y + Pi/2), (x - Pi/2) (y + Pi/2)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, ClippingStyle -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Thanks. It really healped a lot

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and somewhat dirty solution.

```
Legended[
  Show[PIC1, PIC2, PIC3], 
  SwatchLegend[
    {Yellow, Blue, Green}, {"Cos[x] Cos[y]", 
    "-(x-Pi/2) (y+Pi/2)", "(x-Pi/2) (y+Pi/2)"}]]
```

[image: plot]